# How to pass data to controller using ajax and view data accordingly

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

Am using laravel 5.4.
I want to get the products that is created in the last 7 days, 15 days, 30 days and 45 days.

I got the data with the help of ajax. I want to add a where condition to the controller when i got data from the ajax. How can I do it.

My code in ajax:

```
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
   var days = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: '/getcreatedat',
        data: { 'days': days },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

And I want to pass the data here by adding condition:
Controller code:

```
public function category($name, $main){
      $category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->value('id');
      if($category_id == "")
      {
        $all_categories_id = Category::pluck('id');
      }
      else
      {
      $all_categories_id = Category::where('parent_id', $category_id)->pluck('id');
      $all_categories_id->push($category_id);
      }
      $product_id = Product::where('name', 'like','%'.$main.'%')->pluck('id');
      $id = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $product_id)->whereIn('category_id', $all_categories_id)->pluck('id');
      $products = Product::find($id);      

      //Categories Name in Sidebar
      $category = ProductCategory::whereIn('product_id', $id)->pluck('parent_id');
      $category_name = Category::whereIn('id', $category)->pluck('name');

      //Categories Name in dropdown
      $main_categories = Category::where('parent_id', '0')->pluck('name'); 

      //Product Image Mapping         
      $products->map(function ($product) {
      $directory = 'uploads/products/images/'.$product->id;
      $brand = Brand::select('name')->where('id', '=', $product->brand)->pluck('name');
      $brand_name = $brand->first(function($value, $key) {
        return $key == 'name';
      });
      if (is_dir($directory)) {
        $files = scandir ($directory);
        $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
        $product['front_img'] = $img_file;
        $product['brand'] = $brand_name;
        return $product;
      }
        return $product;
      });

      return view('pages/product', compact('main_categories', 'products', 'name', 'category_name'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
   var days = $(this).val();
```

here you are not checking whether the checkbox is checked or not. So make following changes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
        var days = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Now you will get the value of checkbox only when it is check, which is the right logic

Comment: Ya. That i made. I just checked with that. I now need to pass the success data to the controller and add one more where condition in it